# Obtaining Death Certificate Argentina

Tags: immigration, death-records, argentina

My Russian Grandfather escaped in 1948 on a ship to Buenos Aires, I have located the passengers list, his name, Cámara Nacional Electoral in Buenos Aires confirms his registration and official matricul number. I have checked  VI,Anses, Afip, CI and have his cuit number but not information about his passing. I have no idea about the date of his passing and contacted numerous cimeterio without luck. Any clues welcome at home as I can also not find which authorities gave papers to stateless POW released from Spain in 1945. Ship Monte Ayala, Name: Leonide Morosoff Stoupine - 1948 arrival in Buenos Aires.

Comment: Hi Sam! I live in Buenos Aires, and I would like to help you find this information. Do you have any location reference?